# Inventorypath to find the vm location

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

I am using VCenter. Trying to automate the vm creation and deletion by using vijava api's.  Removal of Vm is working fine.When i am trying to clone the vm i am stucked.. 
Structure of VM's

```
localhost
     --Datacenter1
             | ----CLuster1
             |        -----vm1
             |        -----vm2
             |        -----vm3
             |
             | ----Cluster2 
     --DataCenter2
```

Here i am trying to fetch vm3 from this hierachy using the path in the 
VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) si.getSearchIndex().findByInventoryPath("vmpath");

What is the path structure i have to give so that i can obtain the vm from this structure.
I tried by Datacenter1/Cluster1/vm3
But everything throws VMNotfound exception..

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use its path vs its instance uuid?

Comment: No matter the reason.. I think you should use the instance uuidand use the findByUuid method, but Ill give a solution in the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

There are several "hidden" folders in the vSphere inventory. In this case what you need is a path like so:

```
VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) si.getSearchIndex().findByInventoryPath("Datacenter1/vm/vm3");
```

vm is a "hidden" folder that contains all the VirtualMachines in the Datacenter. I suggest using the MOB when you get stuck with inventory stuff like this. https://vcenter/mob

I also suggest moving from vijava to yavijava https://github.com/yavijava/yavijava

Its got a lot of nifty features I have added. Biggest one being logging.